# Interface not working in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to implement Laravel Auth Token (https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token) and so far it's installed ok, but when I try to POST a username/password to it, it fails.  I've traced the issue down to this:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of User given
```

Basically the code runs:

```
$user = $this->users->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
```

.. to retrieve a user (which works: It returns a User model).  It then runs:

```
$this->users->validateCredentials($user, $credentials)
```

That's where the crash happens.  I checked my User model and at the top is:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent {
 ...
}
```

I would think this makes my User model an instance of UserInterface, right?

Is there any way to check what instances my User can represent, and/or debug why the UserInterface isn't applying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, what would make your `User` class an instance of `Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface` would be if it actually implemented the interface. You should have something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, so that worked perfectly - thanks!  I hit some errors about missing 5 methods, however.  I created hollow functions for each one, which bypassed the error, but the trouble is, I'm not sure what they are supposed to do.  They are: getAuthIdentifier(), getAuthPassword(), getRememberToken(), setRememberToken($value), getRememberTokenName().  The best I can think to do is look at ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/GenericUser.php for an example of how they should be implemented..

Comment: Take a look at the implementation provided by default by Laravel, since 4.2: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/UserTrait.php